# Inno Setup: Create custom form

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm working with an Inno Setup. I'm a beginner and I'm not so familiar with it. 
I have two pages in my standard installer that are one after the other and whose elements I need to use (`RepositoryPage` and `ServicePage` (last page)).

RepositoryPage:

[image]

```pascal
procedure CreateRepositoryPage;
var
    i : Integer;
    SqlNamesArray: TArrayOfString;
    LblMonitorService, LblUsername, LblPassword : TNewStaticText;
begin

    RepositoryPage := CreateInputQueryPage(wpSelectComponents, 'Configuration', '' , '');

    { Windows username. RepositoryPage.Edits[2] }
    RepositoryPage.Add('', False);
    { Windows password. RepositoryPage.Edits[3] }
    RepositoryPage.Add('', True);

    LblMonitorService := TNewStaticText.Create(RepositoryPage);
    with LblMonitorService do
    begin
        Parent := RepositoryPage.Surface;
        Left := 0;
        Width := RepositoryPage.SurfaceWidth;
        Height := ScaleY(17);
        AutoSize := False;
        Caption := 'Dashboard service';
    end;

    LblUsername := TNewStaticText.Create(RepositoryPage);
    with LblUsername do
    begin
        Parent := RepositoryPage.Surface;
        Left := 0;
        Top := LblMonitorService.Top + LblMonitorService.Height + ScaleY(17);
        Width := RepositoryPage.SurfaceWidth;
        Height := ScaleY(17);
        AutoSize := False;
        Caption := 'Windows account username (Domain\Username):';
    end;

    RepositoryPage.Edits[0].Top := LblUsername.Top + LblUsername.Height;

    LblPassword := TNewStaticText.Create(RepositoryPage);
    with LblPassword do
    begin
        Parent := RepositoryPage.Surface;
        Left := 0;
        Top := RepositoryPage.Edits[0].Top + RepositoryPage.Edits[0].Height + ScaleY(15);
        Width := RepositoryPage.SurfaceWidth;
        Height := ScaleY(17);
        AutoSize := False;
        Caption := 'Windows account password:';
    end;

    RepositoryPage.Edits[1].Top := LblPassword.Top + LblPassword.Height;


    LogOnAsServiceCheckBox := TNewCheckBox.Create(RepositoryPage);
    with LogOnAsServiceCheckBox do
    begin
        Parent := RepositoryPage.Surface;
        Top := RepositoryPage.Edits[1].Top + RepositoryPage.Edits[1].Height + ScaleY(16);
        Left := 0;
        Width := RepositoryPage.SurfaceWidth;
        Height := ScaleY(17);
        Caption := 'Add "Log on as a service" permission';
        Checked := True;
    end;


    RepositoryPage.Values[0] := ExpandConstant('{computername}') + '\' + ExpandConstant('{username}');
    RepositoryPage.Values[1] := '';

    { Change text color for textboxes }
    RepositoryPage.Edits[1].Font.Color := $ffffff;

end;
```

ServicePage:

[image]

```pascal
[Code]
procedure CreateServicePage;
var
    SSLNameArray : TArrayOfString;
    i : Integer;
begin

    ServicePage := CreateInputQueryPage(RepositoryPage.ID, 'Web server configuration',  '' , '');

    { Username. ServicePage.Edits[0] }
    ServicePage.Add('', False);
    { Password. ServicePage.Edits[1] }
    ServicePage.Add('', True);
    { Confirm Password. ServicePage.Edits[2] }
    ServicePage.Add('', True);

    { Http server configuration }

    {   Http checkbox  }
    HttpServerOptionCheckBox := TNewCheckBox.Create(ServicePage);
    with HttpServerOptionCheckBox do
    begin
        Parent := ServicePage.Surface;
        Top := ScaleY(0);
        Left := 0;
        Width := ScaleX(350);
        Caption := 'HTTP web server';
        Checked := True;
        OnClick := @OnHttpServerOptionCheckBox;
    end;

    {   Label for Http port }
    LblHttpPort := TNewStaticText.Create(ServicePage);
    with LblHttpPort do
    begin
        Parent := ServicePage.Surface;
        Left := ScaleX(15);
        Top := HttpServerOptionCheckBox.Top + HttpServerOptionCheckBox.Height + ScaleY(5);
        Width := ServicePage.SurfaceWidth;
        AutoSize := False;
        TabOrder := 1;
        Caption := 'Server port:';
    end;

    {   Edit for Http port }
    HttpPortTextBox := TNewEdit.Create(ServicePage);
    with HttpPortTextBox do
    begin
        Parent := ServicePage.Surface;
        Top := LblHttpPort.Top + LblHttpPort.Height + ScaleY(2);
        Left := ScaleX(15);
        Width := ScaleX(60);
        Text := '5019';
        Font.Color := $ffffff;
    end;

    {   Test button for testing Http port }
    TestHttpPortButton := TNewButton.Create(ServicePage);
    with TestHttpPortButton do
    begin
        Parent := ServicePage.Surface;
        Top := HttpPortTextBox.Top - ScaleY(2);
        Left := HttpPortTextBox.Width + ScaleX(20);
        Width := ScaleX(75);
        Height := ScaleY(23);
        OnClick := @TestHttpPortButtonOnClick;
        Caption := 'Test';
    end;

    { Checkbox for Http port firewall exception }
    CreateAddFirewallexceptionHttpCheckBox := TNewCheckBox.Create(ServicePage);
    with CreateAddFirewallexceptionHttpCheckBox do
    begin
        Parent := ServicePage.Surface;
        Top := HttpPortTextBox.Top + HttpPortTextBox.Height + ScaleY(5);
        Left := ScaleX(15);
        Width := ScaleX(350);
        Height := ScaleY(17);
        Caption := 'Create a firewall exception for the specified port';
        Checked := True;
    end;

    { //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// }

    { Https server checkbox  }
    HttpsServerOptionCheckBox := TNewCheckBox.Create(ServicePage);
    with HttpsServerOptionCheckBox do
    begin
        Parent := ServicePage.Surface;
        Top := CreateAddFirewallexceptionHttpCheckBox.Top + CreateAddFirewallexceptionHttpCheckBox.Height + ScaleY(20);
        Left := 0;
        Width := ScaleX(120);
        Height := ScaleY(17);
        Caption := 'HTTPS web server';
        Checked := False;
        OnClick := @OnHttpsServerOptionCheckBox;
    end;

    { Https server port label    }
    LblHttpsPort := TNewStaticText.Create(ServicePage);
    with LblHttpsPort do
    begin
        Parent := ServicePage.Surface;
        Left := ScaleX(15);
        Top := HttpsServerOptionCheckBox.Top + HttpsServerOptionCheckBox.Height + ScaleY(2);
        Width := ScaleX(60);
        Height := ScaleY(17);
        AutoSize := False;
        Caption := 'Server port: ';
    end;

    { Https server port edit     }
    HttpsPortTextBox := TNewEdit.Create(ServicePage);
    with HttpsPortTextBox do
    begin
        Parent := ServicePage.Surface;
        Top := LblHttpsPort.Top + LblHttpsPort.Height;
        Left := LblHttpsPort.Left;
        Width := ScaleX(60);
        Height := ScaleY(17);
        Text := '4443';
        Font.Color := $ffffff;
    end;

    { Https server site name label  }
    LblSiteName := TNewStaticText.Create(ServicePage);
    with LblSiteName do
    begin
        Parent := ServicePage.Surface;
        Left := HttpsPortTextBox.Left + HttpsPortTextBox.Width +    ScaleX(10);
        Top := HttpsServerOptionCheckBox.Top + HttpsServerOptionCheckBox.Height + ScaleY(2);
        Width := ScaleX(98);
        Height := ScaleY(17);
        AutoSize := False;
        Caption := 'Host name or IP:';
    end;

    { Https server site name edit }
    HttpsSiteNameTextBox := TNewEdit.Create(ServicePage);
    with HttpsSiteNameTextBox do
    begin
        Parent := ServicePage.Surface;
        Top := LblSiteName.Top + LblSiteName.Height;
        Left := LblSiteName.Left;
        Width := ScaleX(140);
        Height := ScaleY(17);
        Text := '';
        Font.Color := $ffffff;
    end;

    LblSSLName := TNewStaticText.Create(ServicePage);
    with LblSSLName do
    begin
        Parent := ServicePage.Surface;
        Left := HttpsSiteNameTextBox.Left + HttpsSiteNameTextBox.Width + ScaleX(10) ;
        Top := HttpsServerOptionCheckBox.Top + HttpsServerOptionCheckBox.Height + ScaleY(2);
        Width := ScaleX(50);
        Height := ScaleY(17);
        AutoSize := False;
        Caption := 'SSL: ';
    end;

    SSLComboBox := TNewComboBox.Create(RepositoryPage);
    with SSLComboBox do
    begin
        Parent := ServicePage.Surface;
        Style := csDropDown;
        Left := LblSSLName.Left;
        Top := LblSSLName.Top + LblSSLName.Height;
        Width := ScaleX(150);
        Height := ScaleY(17);
        ItemIndex := 0;
    end;

    if not (IsAppUpgrade or IsSameVersion) then begin
         SSLNameArray := GetSSLCertificates();
         for i:= 0 to GetArrayLength(SSLNameArray)-1 do begin
                SSLComboBox.Items.Add(SSLNameArray[i])
         end;
    end;

        {   Test button for testing Https port }
    TestHttpsPortButton := TNewButton.Create(ServicePage);
    with TestHttpsPortButton do
    begin
        Parent := ServicePage.Surface;
        Top := SSLComboBox.Top - ScaleY(2);
        Left := SSLComboBox.Left + SSLComboBox.Width + ScaleX(5);
        Width := ScaleX(75);
        Height := ScaleY(23);
        OnClick := @TestHttpsPortButtonOnClick;
        Caption := 'Test';
    end;

    CreateAddFirewallexceptionHttpsCheckBox := TNewCheckBox.Create(ServicePage);
    with CreateAddFirewallexceptionHttpsCheckBox do
    begin
        Parent := ServicePage.Surface;
        Top := HttpsSiteNameTextBox.Top + HttpsSiteNameTextBox.Height + ScaleY(5);
        Left := ScaleX(15);
        Width := ScaleX(350);
        Height := ScaleY(17);
        Caption := 'Create a firewall exception for the specified port';
        Checked := True;
    end;

    { User managment }
    LblServicePageUser := TNewStaticText.Create(ServicePage);
    with LblServicePageUser do
    begin
        Parent := ServicePage.Surface;
        Top := CreateAddFirewallexceptionHttpsCheckBox.Top + CreateAddFirewallexceptionHttpsCheckBox.Height + ScaleY(15);
        Left := 0;
        Width := ServicePage.SurfaceWidth;
        Height := ScaleY(0);
        AutoSize := False;
        Caption := 'Application user';
    end;

    LblServicePageUsername := TNewStaticText.Create(ServicePage);
    with LblServicePageUsername do
    begin
        Parent := ServicePage.Surface;
        Left := 0;
        Top := LblServicePageUser.Top + LblServicePageUser.Height + ScaleY(5);
        Width := ServicePage.SurfaceWidth;
        Height := ScaleY(17);
        AutoSize := False;
        Caption := 'Application username: ';
    end;

    ServicePage.Values[0] := strMonitorUser;
    ServicePage.Edits[0].Top := LblServicePageUsername.Top + LblServicePageUsername.Height;

    LblServicePagePassword := TNewStaticText.Create(ServicePage);
    with LblServicePagePassword do
    begin
        Parent := ServicePage.Surface;
        Left := 0;
        Top := ServicePage.Edits[0].Top + ServicePage.Edits[0].Height + ScaleY(5);
        Width := ServicePage.SurfaceWidth;
        Height := ScaleY(17);
        AutoSize := False;
        Caption := 'New password: ';
    end;

    ServicePage.Edits[1].Top := LblServicePagePassword.Top + LblServicePagePassword.Height;

    LblServicePageConfirmPassword := TNewStaticText.Create(ServicePage);
    with LblServicePageConfirmPassword do
    begin
        Parent := ServicePage.Surface;
        Left := 0;
        Top := ServicePage.Edits[1].Top + ServicePage.Edits[1].Height + ScaleY(2);
        Width := ServicePage.SurfaceWidth;
        Height := ScaleY(17);
        AutoSize := False;
        Caption := 'Confirm password: ';
    end;

    ServicePage.Edits[2].Top := LblServicePageConfirmPassword.Top + LblServicePageConfirmPassword.Height;

    EnableServicePageElements;

    { Change text color for textboxes }
    ServicePage.Edits[0].Font.Color := $ffffff;
    ServicePage.Edits[1].Font.Color := $ffffff;
    ServicePage.Edits[2].Font.Color := $ffffff;

    OnHttpServerOptionCheckBox( HttpServerOptionCheckBox);
    OnHttpsServerOptionCheckBox( HttpsServerOptionCheckBox);

end;
```

`ConfigForm` contains all elements from `ServicePage` and `RepositoryPage`, it is only used to create a config file (that will be used later) and is also separate from the installer (have not pages before and after). 
How can I make a custom `ConfigForm` shown as an image below?

[image]

Comment: Do I understand right that you want to get rid of your two custom pages and replace them with a single separate window/form? Why? – I also do not understand what exactly you mean by *"separate from the installer"*.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl No, I want to create a CustomForm with all the elements contained in these 2 pages. I'll explain why I need this: I have a common installer where I choose which application I want to install and if I send switch /configure from there then it only opens this configuration form to me for populating and saving a config file, if it is switch /verysilent then it uses that config file and does the background installation without any pop-up windows and without switch, then starts the standard installer (WelcomePage->LicensesPage->SelectDirPage->RepositoryPage ->ServicePage).

Comment: How does *"I want to create a CustomForm with all the elements contained in these 2 pages"* differ from *"you want to get rid of your two custom pages and replace them with a single separate window/form?"* + I do not understand your explanation.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Ok, forget these 2 pages. How can I create a Custom Form (ConfigForm) with the structure shown in the image above (white theme image)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the example of using [`CreateCustomForm` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createcustomform) in [`CodeClasses.iss` example file](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/main/Examples/CodeClasses.iss):

```pascal
procedure FormButtonOnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Form: TSetupForm;
  Edit: TNewEdit;
  OKButton, CancelButton: TNewButton;
begin
  Form := CreateCustomForm();
  try
    Form.ClientWidth := ScaleX(256);
    Form.ClientHeight := ScaleY(128);
    Form.Caption := 'TSetupForm';

    Edit := TNewEdit.Create(Form);
    Edit.Top := ScaleY(10);
    Edit.Left := ScaleX(10);
    Edit.Width := Form.ClientWidth - ScaleX(2 * 10);
    Edit.Height := ScaleY(23);
    Edit.Anchors := [akLeft, akTop, akRight];
    Edit.Text := 'TNewEdit';
    Edit.Parent := Form;

    OKButton := TNewButton.Create(Form);
    OKButton.Parent := Form;
    OKButton.Left := Form.ClientWidth - ScaleX(75 + 6 + 75 + 10);
    OKButton.Top := Form.ClientHeight - ScaleY(23 + 10);
    OKButton.Width := ScaleX(75);
    OKButton.Height := ScaleY(23);
    OKButton.Anchors := [akRight, akBottom]
    OKButton.Caption := 'OK';
    OKButton.ModalResult := mrOk;
    OKButton.Default := True;

    CancelButton := TNewButton.Create(Form);
    CancelButton.Parent := Form;
    CancelButton.Left := Form.ClientWidth - ScaleX(75 + 10);
    CancelButton.Top := Form.ClientHeight - ScaleY(23 + 10);
    CancelButton.Width := ScaleX(75);
    CancelButton.Height := ScaleY(23);
    CancelButton.Anchors := [akRight, akBottom]
    CancelButton.Caption := 'Cancel';
    CancelButton.ModalResult := mrCancel;
    CancelButton.Cancel := True;

    Form.ActiveControl := Edit;
    { Keep the form from sizing vertically since we don't have any controls which can size vertically }
    Form.KeepSizeY := True;
    { Center on WizardForm. Without this call it will still automatically center, but on the screen }
    Form.FlipSizeAndCenterIfNeeded(True, WizardForm, False);

    if Form.ShowModal() = mrOk then
      MsgBox('You clicked OK.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
  finally
    Form.Free();
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This help me a lot to create custom form. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check [Install Designer](http://www.install-designer.com/) for Inno Setup?

That is a new tool that helps you design Inno Setup dialog pages easily without any scripting (WYSIWIG editor with Drag & Drop).

With is it is much faster to create any page in Inno Setup than writing code manually.

(I am developer of that tool and if you have any issues feel free to post any questions here on SO).